# detect elastic search index last modified time

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, timestamp, last-modified

I'm wondering what would be an efficient way to detect the last modified timestamp of an index in Elastic Search. I have read posts of adding a timestamp fields in pipeline but this solution has limitations (e.g. only newly created index supports timestamp update?)

If only a handful of indices are required to track their last modify time, what would be the most efficient way? Would periodic query and compare result between queries give us an approx. last modify time? any other ways to track ES events?

Answer (score 1):

there is a `creation_date` setting, but not a comparable `update_date` one. the reasoning behind this is that updating this for every indexing event would be very expensive, even more so in a distributed environment

you could use something like [`meta`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/mapping-field-meta.html), but it has the same limitation as adding a timestamp to individual documents

Comment: thanks. It's too rush to simply remove event tracking without providing a full alternative solution.